# How to inject services to monitor authentication and storage status?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm using Angular.js to build a client side application with Restangular.
The problem is, I implemented a digest authentication with a wsse header which i have to generate at each request to my REST Server.

I saw that Restangular provide a function : addFullRequestInterceptor().

So now, i'm trying to use it inside my RestangularProvider to configure it in this file restangular.js :

```
// Config Restangular
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(applicationConfig.SERVER_URL);
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor(
    function (element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {

      // Here is my header generation.
      $http.defaults.headers.common['X-WSSE'] =
        TokenHandler.getCredentials(
             AuthHandler.authentication.user.username,
             AuthHandler.authentication.secret); 

      return {
        element: element,
        headers: headers,
        params: params,
        httpConfig: httpConfig
      };
   });
});
```

But i have an injection problem and i can't find out **how to inject my TokenHandler service & my AuthHandler service** to be able to know if the user is already loggedin or not and if he has localstroage or not.

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the `.config` phase the services, like `AuthHandler` and `TokenHandler` are not yet instantiated, so you need to instantiate them (and their dependencies) manually with `$injector` (which is injectable into `config` blocks):

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider, 
                     $injector, 
                     AuthHandlerProvider,
                     TokenHandlerProvider) {
   var AuthHandler = $injector.instantiate(AuthHandlerProvider.$get);
   var TokenHandler = $injector.instantiate(TokenHandlerProvider.$get);

   //...
});
```

Comment: Ok, so i have to transform my service into a provider ? Should i be still able  to use promise in a provider ?

Comment: @davidbonachera, any service has an associated "provider" - a service named `fooService` would have a `fooServiceProvider` that could be injected in the `config` phase. You don't have to do anything extra

Comment: i didn't know that ! i need some more learning on angularjs. it works prefectly now :) Thank you very much.

Comment: in fact i missunderstood something .config is run before services no ? So i cannot access my object content via the provider of my service ? (i'm a bit confused with the notion of environnement in angular, i never know where i am in the app...)

Comment: @davidbonachera This [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies) should help. Config phase is before the services are instantiated. In fact, config is where you could affect some aspects of their instantiation. That's why we need `$injector.instantiate` to manually trigger an instantiation of these services.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation :), Problem Solved !